# Return exact state of the StateWidget

Tags: dart, flutter

Routes in Flutter are creating 'new' instants of the 'StateWidget' they are calling (unless if I misunderstood it)

I've 2 questions (may be can have one answer):

How can I get back for the exact instant that I came from,
And, how can I close the instant of the `StateWidget` if I do not want to come back to it any more, I tried `exit(0)` but it closed the app completely, and crashed when I tried `super.dispose()`

I used the below codes:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: new HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        '/content': (BuildContext context) => new ContentPage(title: 'Content')
      },
    );
  }
```

And switched between the routes as below:

```
new FlatButton(
          child: new Text(
            "Back to home",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
          textColor: new Color(0xFF66BB6A),               
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
          //  exit(0);  // this closed the app completly
          // super.dispose();  // the app crashed
          },
        ),
```

**UPDATE**

When I tried `Navigator.of(context).pop` and the others, the app hanged as shown:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Once I tried using `pushReplacementNamed` the behavior above got fixed, but switched between the 2 States, but did not keep the states status, and created new one instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Navigator.of(context).pop` and it's variations such as `pushReplacement` and `pushReplacementNamed`. Which combines a `push`/`pushNamed` and a `pop`.

Comment: Something weird happened, i updated my question with print screen of that.

Comment: did you try `pushReplacementNamed` ?

Comment: yes, tried both '.pop' and 'pushReplacementNamed' and got the same, did not try others.

Comment: Correction.. Once I tried using `pushReplacementNamed` the behavior above got fixed, but switched between the 2 States, but did not keep the states status, and created new one instead!

Comment: What do you mean ? The whole point of `pushReplacementNamed` is to _not_ keep it.

Comment: mm, what I want is to keep it :) i.e. to be able to retrieve i back as it is latest state/instant.

Comment: Then just us `push` and don't dispose the old one. And when you want to got back, use `pop`

Comment: Thanks, it is fine now, can pls update your answer, and add how can I send parameters/values when I use `push` or `pop`